# How can I search for substring and displayed the full?

Tags: javascript, node.js

how can I search for a substring and displayed the full?
The background of this is that the name of a file is very long with numbers but also the first five letters are always good for matching.

This is my substring for example: FXBew

Here are my Tables which are in my database datein.. you see there is also a table which is named as FXBewertung.

```
[ { Tables_in_datein: 'FXBewertung' },
  { Tables_in_datein: 'GarantieReport' },
  { Tables_in_datein: 'kontoauszug' },
  { Tables_in_datein: 'LiReport' },
  { Tables_in_datein: 'ZSReport' } ]
```

in the next step I have excluded the names as string:

```
FXBewertung
GarantieReport
kontoauszug
LiReport
ZSReport
```

At least the right name (here for example FXBewertung) have to be in my sql query. 
Therefore, I would like to have the correct name output and save as a variable, depending on which file is uploaded.

For Example: FXBew is my substring and then i want FXBewertung.. I have found match() but it doesn't work..

i try this: console.log(Dateiname.match("FXBe")) but it is null..

Dateiname:

```
FXBewertung
GarantieReport
kontoauszug
LiReport
ZSReport
```

Best regards,

Frederic

Comment: You can use contains in modern JS if you don't need any complex RegEx like so: `'biglongstring'.includes('long'); // true`

Comment: @Gavin strings don't have a `contains()` method, but they do have an [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method. Is that what you meant?

Comment: You're absolutely right @PatrickRoberts. My mistake (comment edited with fix).

Comment: You can use `str.startsWith()` if you want to have case insensitivity then lowercase both the string and string to be matched, or use regex with `i` flag

Comment: but if this is 'true' i still do not have the full name.. actually the function match () should show me all...? also includes() is false...

Comment: console.log(Dateiname.includes("FXBew")) -> false

Answer (score 0):

I would use [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and return true when the string starts with your filter string using [string.startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

```js
const data = [ { Tables_in_datein: 'FXBewertung' },
  { Tables_in_datein: 'GarantieReport' },
  { Tables_in_datein: 'kontoauszug' },
  { Tables_in_datein: 'LiReport' },
  { Tables_in_datein: 'ZSReport' } ];

const names = data.map(dataItem => dataItem.Tables_in_datein);

const filteredNames = names.filter(name => name.startsWith('FX'));

console.log(filteredNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have it ;):

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            var Datein = json[i].Tables_in_datein   
            var Dateiname = Datein.toString()
            console.log(Dateiname)

            var match = Dateiname.match(richtigername2)


                if (Dateiname.includes(richtigername2) == true) {

                     var richtigername = match.input

                } else {

                    console.log("Existiert nicht")
                }
        };

        console.log(richtigername)

in json there are Tables_in_datein: 'Name of Table'
```